# REGEXP frustration in Oracle Database

Tags: regex, database, oracle

I have searched and searched and tried several different ways of evaluating these name patterns using `REGEXP_LIKE()` in an Oracle select statement.  If my expression evaluates to true, I'm just putting the original column value into various contrived columns based on which condition it meets as true.  So, I'm just trying to get the first one, and it's not working!

I have a column of names in a database that were free-form typed into one field.  They can be:

```
FirstName LastName
FirstName MiddleInitial LastName
FirstName MiddleInitial. LastName
LastName, FirstName MiddleInitial.
```

Which covers MOST of the cases.  But I'm just trying to evaluate the first pattern to start with, if it matches FirstName LastName.

So, I've tried:

```
(CASE Expressions)
```

- `REGEXP_LIKE(name, '\S+\s?\S+')`  and gotten true for all, even those with 2 whitespaces within the name, like in the case of FirstName MiddleInitial LastName.
- `REGEXP_LIKE(name, '[^\s]+\s?[^\s]+')` and gotten true for all, I thought the [^\s] would exclude whitespace from being allowed anywhere but once between the first name and last name.
- `REGEXP_LIKE(name, '[A-Z,a-z]+" "?[A-Z,a-z]')` and gotten false for all (tried to use the Posix version instead of Perl influenced).

I've probably tried about 10 other variations of this too but I can't remember or type them all out. I'm hoping someone could just get me started on the first matching case of FirstName LastName and then I'll "get it" and go from there!

Comment: I'm not sure to understand: your issue is that you can't find a regexp for the pattern `FirstName LastName` _only_ ? Or are you looking for a pattern matching _all_ your various "free-form" data ?

Comment: I was just trying to start with FirstName LastName ONLY, then I was going to return that name into a column to do a substring function to separate them a certain way.  Then other patterned names would go in their own columns to do a different substring function on, etc.  Eventually I wanted to end up with FirstName, MiddleName, LastName in their own columns.  I think I'm changing my strategy now....

Comment: I think I wasn't understanding the concept of REGEXP evaluation, and I understand it better now. I see why I was getting trues for my expressions, it is a "greedy" function and returns true on the FIRST hit, instead of evaluating the string as a whole. I guess there's lots of modifiers to change the logic, but my head was spinning I think I should be able to figure this out from Silvain's answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FirstName LastName` will match `^[^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+[^[:blank:]]+$`

- `^` from the start of the string
- `[^[:blank:]]+` one or more non-blank
- `[[:blank:]]+` followed by one or more *blank*
- `[^[:blank:]]+` followed by one or more non-blank
- `$` up to the end of the string

---

Starting with Oracle 11g you could use [Perl-influenced Extensions in Oracle Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/ap_posix003.htm#SQLRF55427) . So, you can achieve exactly the same thing by using the more concise pattern `^\S+\s+\S+$`

---

That being said, you probably have to normalize your data using something *like* that:

```
with testdata as (select 'James T. Kirk' ff from dual union all
                  select 'Montgomery Scott' from dual union all
                  select 'Riker, William T.' from dual union all
                  select 'Miles O''Brien' from dual union all
                  select 'Harcourt F Mudd' from dual),
     patterns as (select '^((\S+)\s+(\S+))$' s, '\2' fn, '' mi, '\3' ln from dual union all
                  select '^((\S+)\s+(\S)\s+(\S+))$', '\2' fn, '\3' mi, '\4' ln from dual union all
                  select '^((\S+)\s+(\S)\.\s+(\S+))$', '\2' fn, '\3' mi, '\4' ln from dual union all
                  select '^((\S+),\s+(\S+)\s+(\S)\.)$', '\3' fn, '\4' mi, '\2' ln from dual)

select regexp_replace(ff, s, fn) "first name",
       regexp_replace(ff, s, mi)  "middle initial",
       regexp_replace(ff, s, ln)  "last name"
from testdata cross join patterns
where regexp_like(ff, s)
```

Please, adjust the pattern according to your actual data. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/39008 for a live example.

Comment: Your second regex would work, but the first regex would give a false negative on, for example "Tim Berners-Lee". It'd need to account for non-space and non-alpha characters.

Comment: @Todd You are right. I _think_ this is fixed now, as I've edited my answer to replace `[[:alpha:]]` by `[^[blank]]`. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: What a laugh 'Perl influenced Extensions'! They have one of the best db engines on the planet and still use POSIX.